# What is the functional difference between Edit Self-Service Users & Manage External Users App Permissions?

Tags: customer-community

They seem fairly interchangeable in the context of managing a Customer Community and I'm unsure which is best to provision those users who need to be able to edit and log-in as community users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Self-Service Users is for the [Self-Service Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_selfservice.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.14), while Manage External Users is for the [Customer Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customer_portal_setting_up.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.14). To be pedantic, you should use Edit Self-Service Users if you intend to use the old portal, or Manage External Users for the new portal.

Comment: Thanks- it sounds like (and is borne out through testing) that functionally they are the same, but it's just a best practice to follow what Salesforce's intention are behind them?

Comment: @Justin They are two different permissions for two different products. The first product lasted for many years, but had only basic functionality; comment on cases, browse solutions, limited customization. The second one retired the first, and added reporting, Visualforce, list views, enhanced security options, more objects/fields, etc. That one has been retired by the current product, Customer Communities, which gives us new features and Lightning capability. Each permission was added as each new product came out.